# If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ is a limit ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

In the textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech, [Section 9.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=Er1r0n7VoSEC&pg=PA160), the authors first introduce the definition of **increasing** sequence of ordinals:

> [image]

Then they introduce **cofinality**:

> [image]

My question: how do we prove that $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ is a limit ordinal?

If I take a sequence $\langle \alpha_\nu \mid \nu<1 \rangle$ where $\alpha_0=\omega$. It is clear that the limit of this sequence is $\omega$ and thus $\operatorname{cf}(\omega)=1$, which is a successor ordinal.

I don't know what's wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: Hi @MartinSleziak, is it possible to deduce *If $α$ is a limit ordinal, then $cf(α)$ is a limit ordinal* from the authors' definition of increasing sequence and cofinality?

Comment: From the quote above, it seems that the authors definite limit of a sequence of ordinal numbers only *if $\vartheta$ is a limit ordinal*. (This perhaps does not add to clarify of the definition, but since they define cofinality *only for limit ordinals*, it is probably enough for their purposes.)

Comment: Thank you so much @MartinSleziak! I got it.

Comment: What's wrong with my question that I received a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin Sleziak observed, the definition of limit the text uses applies only to sequences of limit-ordinal length - so $\langle\omega\rangle$ does not count as an increasing sequence of ordinals whose limit is $\omega$.

Personally, I think this isn't quite optimal; another approach is to define $cf(\alpha)$ as the smallest $\lambda$ (limit or not) such that there is a sequence of ordinals $<\alpha$ of length $\lambda$ with every ordinal $<\alpha$ being $\le$ some term in the sequence. Then the cofinality of a successor ordinal is $1$ (consider the sequence $\langle \beta\rangle$ in $\alpha=\beta+1$), and the cofinality of a limit ordinal is a limit ordinal.

- Note that if we replace "$\le$" with "$<$" in the definition above, the cofinality of a successor ordinal becomes undefined since the limit of a sequence of ordinals $<\beta+1$ is at most $\beta$. This isn't really a problem, since nobody talks about the cofinality of successor ordinals, but it is in my opinion a bit annoying.
- Note also that the definition above *does* apply to $0$, and gives the "correct" answer $cf(0)=0$, via the empty sequence.

Comment: Hi @Noah, I don't understand the sentence *... with every ordinal $<α$ being $≤$ some term in the sequence*. If every term in the sequence is less than $\alpha$, how can *... being $≤$ some term in the sequence*?

Comment: @LeAnhDung The point is that if $\gamma<\alpha$, then there needs to be some term $\eta$ in the sequence such that $\gamma\le\eta$.